# Setting up SSL for many domains (Virtual Hosts) on a single server (IP)

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, virtual, hosts

My question is the following: I'm hosting a couple of websites on a web server (Apache on Debian Wheezy) and I want to have ssl on them. Can I have one certificate and use it for every domain or should I have multiple ones? I tried to have one but the problem is that if I first visit example1 with https, then if I try to visit example2 with https, I get the content of the former, while the url is the latter.

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to have https for every website on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need SSL certificates for each domain hosted on the box.

you can have selected domains on SSL but would require tweaking the virtual host file.